# Checkbox not visible in Android 4.x but is visible in Android 5+

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have listview which contains textview and a checkbox.

I am showing the `ListView` in a `DialogFragment`.  The problem is that the checkboxes do not show up for devices(emulator) running Android version 4.1 to 4.4.4. But they show up normally for Android 5.0+. I have been trying to fix this for hours. But no success.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

[[image: Android 4.1, No Checkbox]]

[image: Android 5.1, Checkbox visible]

Listview:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_cats_overlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_game_info">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_select_cats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_overlay_pro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:background="#A6000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Available with \n'Quiz Time Pro'"
            android:textColor="@color/android_green"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Listview row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_row_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_row_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cb_row_item"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cb_row_item"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cb_row_item"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cb_row_item"
    android:text="Category name goes here"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DialogFragment Class inflating the listview:

```
public class SelectGameModeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

boolean[] checkedCategories = new boolean[Constants.CATEGORIES.length + 1];
boolean[] checkedDifficulty = new boolean[Constants.DIFFICULTY_LEVELS.length + 1];

List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> difficultyLevels = new ArrayList<>();

TextView gameInfoTV;
Spinner spinner;

public static SelectGameModeDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
    SelectGameModeDialogFragment frag = new SelectGameModeDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    frag.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
    return frag;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    categories.addAll(Arrays.asList(Constants.CATEGORIES));
    difficultyLevels.addAll(Arrays.asList(Constants.DIFFICULTY_LEVELS));
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_game_mode, container);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final ListView lvCategories = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_select_cats);

    gameInfoTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_game_info);
    gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[0]);

    final TextView proTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_overlay_pro);
    final Button btnPlay = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_restart_game);

    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_gamer_categories);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.game_types_spinner, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (pos == Constants.MODE_MILLIONAIRE
                    || pos == Constants.MODE_UNLIMITED
                    || pos == Constants.MODE_20QUESTIONS
                    || pos == Constants.MODE_60SECONDS) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lvCategories.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = 0;
                lvCategories.setLayoutParams(params);
                proTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_CATEGORIES) {
                MultipleCategoryListAdapter adapter = new MultipleCategoryListAdapter(getActivity(), categories);
                lvCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lvCategories.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                lvCategories.setLayoutParams(params);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_DIFFICULTY) {
                SingleCategoryListAdapter adapter = new SingleCategoryListAdapter(getActivity(), difficultyLevels);
                lvCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lvCategories.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                lvCategories.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            lvCategories.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (pos == Constants.MODE_MILLIONAIRE) {
                gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[0]);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_20QUESTIONS) {
                gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[1]);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_CATEGORIES) {
                gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[2]);
                lvCategories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_60SECONDS) {
                gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[3]);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_UNLIMITED) {
                gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[4]);
            } else if (pos == Constants.MODE_DIFFICULTY) {
                gameInfoTV.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.game_types_info)[5]);
                lvCategories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int spinnerPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            ArrayList<String> cat = new ArrayList<>();
            if (spinnerPosition == Constants.MODE_MILLIONAIRE) {
                goToPlayingFragmentWithCategories(cat, Constants.MODE_MILLIONAIRE);
            } else if (spinnerPosition == Constants.MODE_20QUESTIONS) {
                goToPlayingFragmentWithCategories(cat, Constants.MODE_20QUESTIONS);
            } else if (spinnerPosition == Constants.MODE_CATEGORIES) {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedCategories.length; i++) {
                    if (checkedCategories[i]) {
                        cat.add(categories.get(i));
                    }
                }
                goToPlayingFragmentWithCategories(cat, Constants.MODE_CATEGORIES);
                Arrays.fill(checkedCategories, false);
                System.out.println();
            } else if (spinnerPosition == Constants.MODE_60SECONDS) {
                goToPlayingFragmentWithCategories(cat, Constants.MODE_60SECONDS);
            } else if (spinnerPosition == Constants.MODE_UNLIMITED) {
                goToPlayingFragmentWithCategories(cat, Constants.MODE_UNLIMITED);
            } else if (spinnerPosition == Constants.MODE_DIFFICULTY) {
                String diff = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (checkedDifficulty[i]) {
                        diff = difficultyLevels.get(i);
                    }
                }
                goToPlayingFragmentWithCategories(cat, Constants.MODE_DIFFICULTY, diff);
            }
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button btnBack = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_game_mode_back);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The checkbox color for Android 4.x is black, so it was blending with the black background. Fixed it by using AppCompatCheckBox instead of CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the text of the `CheckBox`?

That way your `ListView` item could just be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_row_item"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Category name goes here"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

Comment: I did not think of this. Thanks I'll try this get back to you.

Comment: I did what you said but still I checkbox is not visible. I can only see the checkbox text. May be it has got something to do with theme? Backward compatibility?

Comment: you may need to look at writing your own adapter.  ArrayAdapter is only useful for very simple data.   It will look something like - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40259628/1856361